# Array access in MASM

Tags: arrays, assembly, x86, masm

I'm having some difficulty with my array accessing in MASM. I've got a very large array and a temp variable like so:

```
.data
array DWORD 65000 DUP (0)
temp DWORD 0
```

In my main, I've got this to fill it:

```
mov esi, offset array
mov edi, 0
mov ecx, 0

fill:
mov [esi], ecx
add esi, 4
inc ecx
cmp ecx, 65000
jl fill
mov esi, offset array ;reset the array location to the start
```

After, I want to access the array with this loop:

```
mark:
mov temp, 4 ;get another 4 to temp to move along the array
add esi, temp ;add temp to esi to keep moving
mov edx, [esi] ;access the current value
cmp esi, 20 ;just trying to get first few elements
jmp mark
exit
main ENDP
END main
```

I always have an access violation error, with the break at the line where I try to access the current value. This occurs on the very first loop as well. Any idea why this is happening? Thanks!

Comment: Your second loop is infinite. You compare `esi` to 20 (which isn't going to happen - try `cmp esi, offset array + 20`) and then jump unconditionally to `mark`. `jl` is signed, `jb` is unsigned.

Comment: Thanks, I went ahead and applied that. If you've got the time, can you explain modifying the array in your answer? Maybe explain the process a bit, I seem to think there's a distinction between simply accessing and actually modifying the values.

Comment: I suppose `mov ecx, [esi]` would be "simply accessing" the array. `mov [esi], ecx` would be "modifying the values". Your "fill" loop modifies the array, since it was initialized to zeros.

Answer (score 0):

Your code will work to an extent, however:

```
mark:
mov temp, 4
add esi, temp  ;Incrementing before first loop means you miss the first stored value
mov edx, [esi]
cmp esi, 20    ;ESI is the address your are accessing, not a count
jmp mark       ;This loop will be infinite
```